# Install elixir on M1 mac

Tags: installation, erlang, elixir, homebrew, apple-m1

I tried to install Elixir on my M1 mac using brew, as explained [here](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html). After installation, `elixir --version` returns `segmentation fault elixir --version.`.

After reading [this](https://elixirforum.com/t/segmentation-fault-after-update-elixir-and-erlang/39871/7), I tried the suggested changes, updated the files and ran `brew reinstall elixir`, but I still get the same `segmentation fault elixir --version.`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this up and running with (some recent version of) Elixir on a M1 mac? (MacBook Air (M1, 2020) Apple M1 16 GB)?

Comment: Use [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. [Install asdf](http://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_1-install-dependencies).
2. Install the [erlang plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang).

   - Make sure to read the "Before `asdf install`" section.
   - The "Getting Erlang documentation" section is good to know too.
     TLDR: `export KERL_BUILD_DOCS="yes"`
   - `asdf plugin add erlang https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang.git`
3. `asdf install erlang latest` + wait for erlang to build.
4. `asdf global erlang latest`
5. Install the [elixir plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir).

   - `asdf plugin-add elixir https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir.git`
6. `asdf install elixir latest`
7. `asdf global elixir latest`
8. `iex` to test. Done!

---

Bonus: `export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"` to get shell history in `iex`.

Comment: Even after following the steps the Elixir version stays the same. I wanted to downgrade elixir version globally, followed the steps but elixir --version returns the same version. - M2 Mac

Comment: @manuka_m you probably have something in earlier in your `PATH` overriding the settings.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip need help, followed above steps, mix command throws error, detailed error here https://stackoverflow.com/q/76844553/11141189