# Installing Phoenix 1.7.7 with Erlang 26 gives segmentation fault on Mac M1

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, apple-m1

after upgrading Elixir and Erlang 26 with homebrew, installing Phoenix causes a segmentation fault:

```
$ mix archive.install hex phx_new
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Resolution completed in 0.017s
New:
  phx_new 1.7.7
* Getting phx_new (Hex package)
All dependencies are up to date
Compiling 11 files (.ex)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install elixir on M1 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993494/install-elixir-on-m1-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some digging, I found that homebrew was configured for x86 architecture with Rosetta active, instead arm64.

To check your CPU architecture, run `uname -m`

```
$ uname -m 
arm64
```

Check your homebrew configuration:

```
$ brew config
...
macOS: 13.4.1-x86_64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 14.3
Rosetta 2: true
```

to switch it to arm64, run:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

then verify that the architecture is configured correctly:

```
$ brew config
...
macOS: 13.4.1-arm64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 14.3
Rosetta 2: false
```

Then reinstall Elixir and Erlang

```
brew reinstall elixir erlang
```

and install Phoenix via `mix archive.install hex phx_new`