# Elixir install dependencies command `mix deps.get` is throwing error

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Getting error when installing Elixir dependencies, all Mix command are throwing same exception

```
23:31:44.447 [notice] Application ssl exited: exited in: :ssl_app.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) could not call Module.put_attribute/3 because the module xyz.MixProject is already compiled
            (elixir 1.15.4) lib/module.ex:2310: Module.assert_not_readonly!/2
            (elixir 1.15.4) lib/module.ex:2007: Module.__put_attribute__/5
            (ssl 11.0.2) ssl_app.erl:35: :ssl_app.stop/1
            (kernel 9.0.2) application_master.erl:293: :application_master.start_it_old/4

23:31:44.455 [notice] Application public_key exited: :stopped

23:31:44.455 [notice] Application asn1 exited: :stopped

23:31:44.455 [notice] Application crypto exited: :stopped

23:31:44.456 [error] Task #PID<0.113.0> started from #PID<0.98.0> terminating
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:ssl, {:bad_return, {{:ssl_app, :start, [:normal, []]}, {:EXIT, {%ArgumentError{message: "could not call Module.put_attribute/3 because the module xyz.MixProject is already compiled"}, [{Module, :assert_not_readonly!, 2, [file: ~c"lib/module.ex", line: 2310]}, {Module, :__put_attribute__, 5, [file: ~c"lib/module.ex", line: 2007]}, {:ssl_app, :stop, 1, [file: ~c"ssl_app.erl", line: 35]}, {:application_master, :start_it_old, 4, [file: ~c"application_master.erl", line: 293]}]}}}}}}
    (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/utils.ex:661: Mix.Utils.read_httpc/1
    (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/utils.ex:589: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Utils.read_path/2
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/task/supervised.ex:101: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/4
Function: #Function<5.80278363/0 in Mix.Utils.read_path/2>
    Args: []
** (EXIT from #PID<0.98.0>) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:ssl, {:bad_return, {{:ssl_app, :start, [:normal, []]}, {:EXIT, {%ArgumentError{message: "could not call Module.put_attribute/3 because the module xyz.MixProject is already compiled"}, [{Module, :assert_not_readonly!, 2, [file: ~c"lib/module.ex", line: 2310]}, {Module, :__put_attribute__, 5, [file: ~c"lib/module.ex", line: 2007]}, {:ssl_app, :stop, 1, [file: ~c"ssl_app.erl", line: 35]}, {:application_master, :start_it_old, 4, [file: ~c"application_master.erl", line: 293]}]}}}}}}
        (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/utils.ex:661: Mix.Utils.read_httpc/1
        (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/utils.ex:589: anonymous fn/2 in Mix.Utils.read_path/2
        (elixir 1.15.4) lib/task/supervised.ex:101: Task.Supervised.invoke_mfa/2
        (elixir 1.15.4) lib/task/supervised.ex:36: Task.Supervised.reply/4
```

Tried solutions

1. https://dev.to/onpointvn/installing-erlang-elixir-on-m1-macs-1b8g
2. https://rajrajhans.com/2022/10/installing-elixir-on-mac-m1/

Followed https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang#osx section before installing erlang

**MacBook Pro M2** - OS 13.4.1

**Terminal** - Rosetta

**OpenSSL** 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023)

**Erlang/OTP** 26 [erts-14.0.2] [source] [64-bit

**Elixir** 1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)

**Mix** 1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)

**Node** v18.15.0

**NPM** 9.5.0

.zshrc file
[image]

Do anyone know why I'm getting error related to SSL? and how I can solve it?

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76848595/elixir-mix-command-throws-error-could-not-call-module-put-attribute-3-because

Answer (score 0):

On native terminal install homebrew and follow https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#macos

Make sure all required dependencies must be installed with same homebrew

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76957979/11141189