# Elixir `mix` command throws error `could not call Module.put_attribute/3 because the module Helloworld.MixProject is already compiled`

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Setup new project with command `mix new project_name` it setup everything without any
error or warning message, cd to project and ran command `iex -S mix` it throws error

[image]

lib/helloworld.ex

```
defmodule Helloworld do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for `Helloworld`.
  """

  @doc """
  Hello world.

  ## Examples

      iex> Helloworld.hello()
      :world

  """
  def hello do
    :world
  end
end
```

Version installed on system

```
MacBook Pro M2 - OS 13.4.1
Terminal - Rosetta
OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.1.2 1 Aug 2023)
Erlang/OTP 26 [erts-14.0.2] [source] [64-bit
Elixir 1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)
Mix 1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)
Node v18.15.0
NPM 9.5.0
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you edit the question and add the contents of `lib/helloworld.ex`?

Comment: @Dogbert updated question, lib/helloworld.ex has default content generated by mix

Comment: What's really strange is that the error is in the `@` processing in `Helloworld`, and yet the closed module reported in the error is `Helloworld.MixProject` 

Comment: For shits and giggles, throw up your `mix.exs`

Comment: @Dogbert Is it miss configuration of elixir? I followed this to setup elixir on MacOs m2  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71000268/11141189

Comment: Try a `mix clean` and see what happens.  I agree that this is really a strange issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install elixir on Rosetta terminal, and after switching to native terminal, was getting same error, so uninstalled everything related to elixir from Rosetta terminal, and on native terminal installed homebrew and followed https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#macos

Make sure all required dependencies must be installed with same homebrew

Answer (score -1):

I think you can follow this instruction to install elixir for MacOS:
https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#macos